# Download Google Chart as jpeg instead of png?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am currently downloading Google Charts as png with the following code:

```
var imgUri = my_chart.getImageURI();
var url  = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
linkPNG = document.createElement("a");
linkPNG.href = imgUri;
linkPNG.download = title+".png";
link.click();
```

It works fine. Unfortunately, my users need a jpeg instead of a png, and my usual

```
var imgURL = my_chart.toDataURL( "image/jpeg" );
```

doesn't seem to work with Google Charts. How can I download the charts as .jpg instead of .png?

Comment: The MDN api documentation has a nice example for converting images. You just need to modify the code a bit. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time looking through the obfuscated source of the visualization library, I have determined it would be easier to just recreate the image from the data URI rather than try to change the original export type. You can load the data URI with an image, draw it on a canvas, and convert it back to a data URI.

```
var img = new Image();
img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    link.download = title + '.jpg';
    link.click();
});
img.src = my_chart.getImageURI();
```

Some error handling probably wouldn't be a bad idea either.

Comment: I was just about to say that you need to select the canvas 2d context instead of drawing directly on the canvas, and then you edited it in the nick of time. This works great. Only thing I'd add is that because of transparency issues I added `ctx.fillStyle="#FFFFFF"; ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);` before `ctx.drawImage(img,0,0)`

Comment: Also, you need to change `link.download = title + '.png';` to `link.download = title + '.jpg';`

Comment: Ah, good points. I was actually writing some canvas code for a project of mine when I realized that I forgot to draw to the context in my answer I wrote yesterday so I came back to fix it. What a coincidence.